# Why can we limit the memory the RocksDB database cache can use but not for ParityDB?

Tags: cli, rocks-db, parity-db

In the Substrate CLI why can we limit the memory that the RocksDB database cache can use if we choose to use it [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/cli/src/config.rs#L220), but we're not given the option to limit the memory that ParityDB uses if we choose that database instead [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/cli/src/config.rs#L221)?

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation in [this question and answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/how-are-we-now-able-to-use-the-kvdb-rust-library-with-paritydb-as-a-key-value-st/7581#7581), I discovered that both RocksDB and ParityDB are both persistent key-value (KV) stores, but that ParityDB uses "OS page cache" instead of "custom data caching", where it states in the [Substrate Documentation here](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/state-transitions-and-storage/) that they use key-value cache because *"accessing trie data is costly"*. In the ParityDB README [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-db#no-cache) it states that the ParityDB *"Database does not implement any custom data caching. Instead, it relies on OS page cache. Performance of a large database therefore depends on how much system memory is available to be used in OS page cache."*