# How are we now able to use the kvdb Rust library with ParityDB as a key-value store abstraction?

Tags: rocks-db, parity-db

At the moment building the Substrate repository requires RocksDB library librocksdb-sys and all its native dependencies to be pulled in, but it also supports testing out the *"faster and more efficient"* "experimental" embedded [ParityDB](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-db) using the `--database paritydb` flag, which is also a persistent KV store that uses [OS page cache instead of custom data caching](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-db#no-cache), with interesting [RAM](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11513) performance when syncing. However [validator documentation](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-management) still recommends using the RocksDB backend.

Meanwhile in this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13177) @bkchr mentioned that whilst Substrate compiles on aarch64 there isn't official support for aarch64-linux-android on Android, but @koute and also @gilescope in this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13354) suggested adding a feature flag to the Substrate CLI so building with RocksDB could be optionally disabled because some restless users want to test Substrate on their mobile devices.

I understand that RocksDB is a Key-Value (KV) database by Facebook and @debris has previously mentioned that it is faster than Google's LevelDB. I also read that at some stage Parity migrated to using [blooms-db](https://github.com/debris/blooms-db) (an implementation of a Bloom Filter to reduce overall disk reads), where the blooms are a database layer before the kvdb RocksDB. The [Substrate documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/state-transitions-and-storage/) explains the different trie layers of abstraction.

In various Cargo.toml files of the Substrate repository, there are dependencies like:

```
kvdb
kvdb-rocksdb
kvdb-memorydb
parity-db
```

Previously in an earlier version [kvdb = "0.1.0"](https://docs.rs/kvdb/0.1.0) it was a *"Key-Value store abstraction with RocksDB backend"*, rather than being *"generic"*.

So when I was reviewing the benchmarking code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/bench/src/generator.rs#L32) where they generate a trie using the db type `kvdb::KeyValueDB` from the `kvdb` library, I wondered why we weren't benchmarking the generation of a trie with ParityDB too, and how could we use the kvdb Rust library with ParityDB as a key-value store abstraction, or what was the equivalent library that was being used by ParityDB?

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer inspection of that benchmarking code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/bench/src/generator.rs#L32) where they generate a trie using the db type `kvdb::KeyValueDB`, I noticed in the Cargo.toml file that we were now using version of [kvdb = "0.13.0"](https://docs.rs/kvdb/0.13.0) which is now a *"Generic key-value trait"*.

Initially I was confused because in an earlier version [kvdb = "0.1.0"](https://docs.rs/kvdb/0.1.0) it was a *"Key-Value store abstraction with RocksDB backend"*. So it appears substantial work has been performed by Parity to make that abstraction *generic* so that the trait [`KeyValueDB`](https://docs.rs/kvdb/0.13.0/kvdb/trait.KeyValueDB.html) is a *"Generic key-value database"* that may be used by ParityDB's embedded in-memory `kvdb-memorydb = "0.13.0"` library or RocksDB's `kvdb-rocksdb = "0.17.0"` library.